# Habitat challenge: File **.scn does not exist error encountered when running DD-PPO script

Tags: machine-learning, navigation, reinforcement-learning, robotics

I am trying to set up AI habitat and habitat challenge and came across this issue when I was trying to run the DD-PPO training script indicated here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-challenge#pointnavobjectnav-baselines-and-dd-ppo-training-starter-code

I have download the Gibson dataset following the above instructions and extract the dataset to folder `habitat-challenge/habitat-challenge-data/data/scene_datasets/gibson/` as indicated. I downloaded the 1.5 GB Habitat challenge dataset and it contained `.glb` and `.navmesh` files. However, when I tried running the DD-PPO script by
`sh habitat_baselines/rl/ddppo/single_node.sh` from the habitat-lab directory, it gave me errors saying that there aren't `.scn` files in the `habitat-challenge/habitat-challenge-data/data/scene_datasets/gibson/` directory.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue or where to find these `.scn` files?

[image: Screen shot of error message]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is only a warning and does not affect the pointnav or objectnav challenges.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-challenge/issues/87#issuecomment-920540129